# How to solve linear equation using Matlab?

Tags: matlab

```
A= [1 2 3;3 4 5;5 6 7], 
B=[1;1;1].
```

I need to solve the equation $AX=B$. Here am using Matlab code like

```
 X=linsolve(A,B).
```

But, using this a warning is occurred...

```
"Warning: Matrix is close to singular or badly scaled. Results may be inaccurate. 
RCOND = 1.541976e-18."
```

How to correct it?

Answer (score 3):

(1) First and easiest way to solve it: NOT using Matlab for *this* easy linear system that you can solve with a pencil and a piece of paper.   :-)   For instance, by means of [Gaussian elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination)

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1   &  2   &  3   &  |   &   1  \\
3   &  4   &  5   &  |   &   1  \\
5   &  6   &  7   &  |   &   1
\end{pmatrix}
\longrightarrow \dots \longrightarrow
\begin{pmatrix}
1   &   0   &  -1   & |  & -1  \\
0   &   1   &   2   & |  &  1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Which tells you that the solution set of the system are all vectors of the form $(-1, 1, 0) + z (1, -2, 1)$.

(2) Secondly, if you're lazy to do those previous calculations, you can even ask Matlab to do them for you: the command "rref" reduces matrices to row-echelon form:

> > A = [1 2 3; 3 4 5; 5 6 7]

A =

```
 1     2     3
 3     4     5
 5     6     7
```

> > b = [1 1 1]'

b =

```
 1
 1
 1
```

> > Ab = [A b]

Ab =

```
 1     2     3     1
 3     4     5     1
 5     6     7     1
```

> > rref(Ab)

ans =

```
 1     0    -1    -1
 0     1     2     1
 0     0     0     0
```

(3) The reason why Matlab doesn't like this system is because its matrix $A$ is not full rank (you can see that row of zeros appearing over there). Hence, the system could have no solution at all (if we hadn't that $0$ on the fourth column, third row); or, as it happens in the present situation, have an infinite number of them. Despite of this, Matlab tries hard and finds a solution, but warning you that, since the matrix $A$ is singular, "results may be inaccurate".

> > X = A\b
> >     Warning: Matrix is close to singular or badly scaled. Results may be inaccurate. RCOND =  1.850372e-18.

X =

-4.0000
    7.0000
   -3.0000

(4) So, it's always good to know in advance which kind of system have you got: the [Rouché-Capelli theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem) (also known as "Rouché-Frobenius") tells you everything you need to know about linear systems. And Matlab can help you to do the computations:

> > rank(A)

ans =

```
 2
```

> > rank(Ab)

ans =

```
 2
```

This tells you that the solution set is not empty and it's a straight line (dimension of the solution set $= 3 - \mathrm{rank}\ A = 1$).